# python iterating through and writing to a file

Tags: python

I need to write a function that opens two files and if a certain comparison is true write the result to a third file:

```
def crack_pass_file(pass_filename,words_filename,out_filename):
    f1=open(pass_filename)
    f2=open(words_filename)
    f3=open(out_filename,'w')
    for line1 in f1:
        x=make_dictionary(line1.split(":"))
        password=x["password"]
        name=x["account"]
        for line2 in f2:
            if (check_pass(line2.strip(),password)==True):
                f3.write(name + "="+line2.strip())
```

File f1 is a file containing:

```
root:VgzdTLne0kfs6:0:0:Corema Latterll:/home/root:/bin/bash
checani:IqAFDoIjL2cDs:1:1:Pengpu Checani:/home/checani:/bin/bash
rkrakow:DLD3nJmCvt3pY:2:2:Rodentia Krakow:/home/rkrakow:/bin/bash
forkland:oWMVyy1FTdNL6:3:3:Forkland Maskins:/home/forkland:/bin/bash
obongo:O44lPEloqk5tY:4:4:Obongo Obwalden:/home/obongo:/bin/bash
pglenda:xboW5dHcsqvSQ:5:5:Pahsien Glenda:/home/pglenda:/bin/bash
madel:qEHvJXMkTSAZA:6:6:Madel Aporosa:/home/madel:/bin/bash
ssauks:Q3Kz1z7eAiwjg:7:7:Schober Sauks:/home/ssauks:/bin/bash
slajoie:wWTHgoE8SC8W6:8:8:Scheiner Lajoie:/home/slajoie:/bin/bash
tieton:RWORYLxRSSzMU:9:9:Lerwa Tieton:/home/tieton:/bin/bash
```

where each line has a user, a password, and a bunch of other things.  For line 1 root is the user and VgzdTLne0kfs6 is the encrypted password.  Same format is used for every other line.  What I need to do is take the encrypted password and see if calling crypt on a password in the other file, f2, which contains a giant list of words in alphabetical order like:

```
embordering
emborders
emboscata
embosk
embosked
embosking
```

will make that password into the encrypted password. 
I already have the function that does that and it works:

```
def check_pass(plain,enc):
    s = enc[0:2]
    x = crypt.crypt(plain, s)
    if x==enc: return True
    else: return False
```

also here is the makedictionary function that I use to make a dictionary out of every line of file 1, also works Ive tested it:

```
def make_dictionary(s):
    d={}
    d["account"]=s[0]
    d["shell"]=s[6]
    d["UID"]=int(s[2])
    d["GID"]=int(s[3])
    d["GECOS"]=s[4]
    d["directory"]=s[5]
    d["password"]=s[1]
    return d
```

when I test this it writes:
root=stroam 
to the output file, which is the decrypted password for the first user but doesnt write any of the rest.  This should be the result:

```
root=stroam
checani=asarta
rkrakow=sinklike
obongo=yawnful
madel=aviatic
tieton=dagesh
pglenda=sngissa
forkland=relliarb
slajoie=mu2j1k
ssauks=EGaFeIHC
```

I found all these words(yawnful, aviatic, etc ) in the words file but for some reason they are not being matched.  Ive also tried doing like:
check_pass("asarta","IqAFDoIjL2cDs") and some others and they all return true so Im confused why more of them arent printed out to my output file.

Comment: sorry but I'm not following... do you basically want to take 2 files compare each file line by line and write the matches to a 3rd file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to evaluate every line in `f1` against every line in `f2`.  But you consume every line in `f2` on the first iteration through `f1`.  On the second iteration, `f2` is empty and you won't enter the body of this loop.

```
for line1 in f1:
# ...
    for line2 in f2:
```

Instead, outside of your `for line in f1` loop, generate a list of the lines in f2 (and optionally f1) like so:

```
f2_lines = [line2 for line2 in f2]
...
for line1 in f1:
```

Now you can use

```
for line2 in f2_lines:
```

in the body of your `f1` loop.

Comment: Why bother with a `list` comprehension? `f2_lines = list(f2)` would accomplish the same goal faster and more simply.

Comment: Indeed, that's better still.

Comment: this just makes a string list out of the file? perfect I need that.  If I do that does that automatically get rid of the newline char at the end of the strings?

Comment: Yes, after `f2_lines = list(f2)`, `f2_lines` will be a list of the lines in the `f2` file.

Comment: is there any way I can get rid of all the newlines when I make this list other than individually doing so in a loop with strip()?

Comment: Yes, `f2_lines = [line2.strip() for line2 in f2]`.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you iterate `f2`, you exhaust the iterator, and all future iterations of `f2` are loops that don't execute at all. Either load all the lines of `f2` into a `list` so it can be iterated multiple times, or call `f2.seek(0)` after exhausting it to reset the file pointer.